# Ajax changing the entire sql query

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

http://rimi-classified.com/ad-list/west-bengal/kolkata/electronics-and-technology

The above link has a filter in the left. I am trying to use ajax to get city from state. but as the ajax is triggered the entire query is changing.

```
SELECT * FROM (`ri_ad_post`)
WHERE `state_slug` =  'west-bengal'
AND `city_slug` =  'kolkata'
AND `cat_slug` =  'pages'   
AND `expiry_date` > '2014-03-21'
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

It is taking the controller name in the query (controller name is pages).

The actual query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`ri_ad_post`)
WHERE `state_slug` =  'west-bengal'
AND `city_slug` =  'kolkata'
AND `cat_slug` =  'electronics-and-technology'   
AND `expiry_date` > '2014-03-21'
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

// Controller

```
public function ad_list($state,$city,$category,$sub_cat=FALSE)
{
    if($state===NULL || $city===NULL || $category===NULL)
    {
        redirect(base_url());
    }

    $data['ad_list'] = $this->home_model->get_adlist($state,$city,$category,$sub_cat);



    $this->load->view('templates/header1', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/search', $data);
    $this->load->view('ad-list', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
}
public function get_cities()
{
    $state_id =  $this->input->post('state');
    echo $this->city_model->get_cities($state_id);
}
```

// Model

```
public function get_adlist($state,$city,$category,$sub_cat=FALSE)
{
    if ($sub_cat === FALSE)
    {
        $this->db->where('state_slug', $state);
        $this->db->where('city_slug', $city);
        $this->db->where('cat_slug', $category); 
        $this->db->where('expiry_date >', date("Y-m-d"));
        $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
        $query = $this->db->get('ad_post');
    }

    $this->db->where('state_slug', $state);
    $this->db->where('city_slug', $city);
    $this->db->where('cat_slug', $category); 
    $this->db->where('sub_cat_slug', $sub_cat); 
    $this->db->where('expiry_date >', date("Y-m-d"));
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get('ad_post');



    return $query->result_array();
    //echo $this->db->last_query();
}
```

//ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#state_id').change(function () {
                var selState = $(this).val();
                alert(selState);
                console.log(selState);
                $.ajax({   
                    url: "pages/get_cities", 
                    async: false,
                    type: "POST", 
                    data : "state="+selState, 
                    dataType: "html", 

                    success: function(data) {
                    $('#city').html(data);
                    $("#location_id").html("<option value=''>--Select location--</option>");
                    }
                })
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Please help me how to solve this issue. Please check the url I have provided and try to select a state from the filter section the problem will be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

1. In .js what is the value of selState ?
2. In your model, you should `if() else()` instead of just a if, because your query will get override.
3. Where is the get_cities function ? Can we see it ?
4. On your url, the problem is that your ajax url doesn't return a real ajax call but an entire HTML page which is "harder" to work with. Try to change it into json (for dataType's ajax()) You should only do in your php something like this :

in your controller :

```
public function get_cities()
{
    $state = $this->input->post('state');
    //Do the same for $cat
    if (!$state) {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => 'no state selected'));
        return 0;
    }

    $get_cities = $this->model_something->getCitiesByStateName($state);
    echo json_encode($get_cities);
}
```

1. You should definitely send with ajax the $cat info

Comment: Thing is that I dont want to change the main query. The ajax should effect only the city change. When I will submit the form then only the main query should change

Comment: Edit : How do you get the cat info ? How do you retrieve it, because on your url, it is empty on request.